# Java Spark | UDT error during cassandra insert - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "order_total" does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Java Spark dataframe not able to insert into Cassandra UDT column and getting the below error.

How to construct this UDT column in Dataframe Select or by other ways? Appreciate your inputs in advance.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "order_total" does not exist.
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:254)
```

Spark version 2.0.2

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

public class testpoc {

  public static String host = "$$";
  public static String port = "$$";
  public static String username = "$$";
  public static String password = "$$";
  public static String keyspace = "$$";
  public static String tablename = "$$";
  public static String filePath = "$/Orders_00000.csv";

  public static StructType overall_total_udt = new StructType()
         .add("order_total", DataTypes.StringType, false);

  public static StructType orderType = new StructType()
         .add("id", DataTypes.StringType, false)
         .add("order_date", DataTypes.TimestampType, true)
         .add("totals",  overall_total_udt, true);

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

      SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
      if (sparkConf.getOption("spark.master").isEmpty()) { sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]"); }
      sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host);
      sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", port);
      sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username",username);
      sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password);
      sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");

      //Spark Session
      SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

      Dataset<Row> DF1 = spark
              .read().format("csv")
              .option("header", "true")
              .option("delimiter", "\t")
              .load(filePath);

      DF1.show(false);

      Dataset<Row>  DF2 = DF1.select(
                col("ORDER_NO").as("id"),
                unix_timestamp(col("ORDER_DATE"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp").as("order_date"),
                struct(col("TOTAL_AMOUNT")).as("totals")
        );

      DF2 = DF2.map((MapFunction<Row,Row>) row -> row, RowEncoder.apply(orderType));
      DF2.show(false);

      DF2.write()
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .option("keyspace", keyspace)
         .option("table", tablename)
         .mode(SaveMode.Append)
         .save();

/*
**Cassandra table structure**
CREATE TYPE myspace.overall_total_udt (order_total text);

CREATE TABLE myspace.jorder (
id text, 
order_date timestamp, 
totals frozen<myspace.overall_total_udt>,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
*/

      spark.stop();
    }

}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "order_total" does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:254)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.scala:253)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UserDefinedType$$anon$1$$anonfun$convertPF$1$$anonfun$3.apply(UserDefinedType.scala:53)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UserDefinedType$$anon$1$$anonfun$convertPF$1$$anonfun$3.apply(UserDefinedType.scala:50)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UserDefinedType$$anon$1$$anonfun$convertPF$1.applyOrElse(UserDefinedType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:41)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UserDefinedType$$anon$1.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(UserDefinedType.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.NullableTypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:54)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.UserDefinedType$$anon$1.convert(UserDefinedType.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter$$anonfun$readColumnValues$1.apply$mcVI$sp(SqlRowWriter.scala:26)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:24)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.SqlRowWriter.readColumnValues(SqlRowWriter.scala:12)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.BoundStatementBuilder.bind(BoundStatementBuilder.scala:99)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:106)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:233)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$writeInternal$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:112)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:145)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:210)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I referred this answer, but still not able to achieve it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651345/2636642

Comment: What is your table structure? Perform describe table name in cqlsh

Comment: CREATE TYPE myspace.overall_total_udt (order_total text);

CREATE TABLE myspace.jorder (
id text, 
order_date timestamp, 
totals frozen<myspace.overall_total_udt>,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

Comment: @AlexOtt added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datastax team gave this solution.

```
 DF3 = DF2.selectExpr(
                "CAST (id AS STRING) AS id",
                "CAST (order_date AS TIMESTAMP) AS order_date",
                "NAMED_STRUCT('order_total', CAST (totals AS STRING)) as totals"
                );
```